# Understanding shared Objects with Threads and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, reference

I am new to Java and reading about Synchronization I have a question

I'm not quite sure how this still works so I would like to ask:

e.g. I have a class called 'Math' with synchronized methods of adding and removing
then create an object of it

```
Math m = new Math();
```

and I start 3 threads and pass this object (m) to all.
I know that they will work into the same object and each thread will queue as expected

but what if each thread created their own object?

```
Math m = new Math();
```

they wouldn't work with the same synchronized methods right?

Comment: Correct , if the methods are not static yes you are right. Each thread will hold lock on different instance of Math. if you have sycn block instead of sycn method you could use the same object in your case ( if you are not handling instance varaible inside methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each thread created their own Math object, they would all be independent of each other; they wouldn't be shared - hence not work with the same synchronised methods (unless they are static methods as Mani has pointed out). However, be careful if the Math object has a static member which is used in the synchronised methods - you will still need to provide a locking construct around it if any of the methods change the state of it.

Answer (score 1):

No they didn't work with same methods. But it can depend on Math object.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing here you need to understand is `Class` level lock and `Instance` level lock.

### 1. Instance Level Lock

Like in your first case, all threads share the same object, so every thread need to obtain the only one lock to be able to invoke those methods.

e.g.

```
Class Math {
    synchronized public void add(){}
    synchronized public void decrease(){}
}
```

Both of `add` and `decrease` are instance method. So if two threads are operate in different instance, they will not effect each other.

### 2. Class Level Lock

```
Class Math {
    synchronized public static void add(){}
    synchronized public static void decrease(){}
}
```

In this case, `add` and `decrease` can be invoked without create a Math Object, they a Class level lock, all threads use `Math.add` or `Math.decrease` should obtain the same lock.